# Database free NUnit tests

Tags: database, tdd, nunit

How can I test my code (TDD) for standard CRUD operations without having a database. Is it possible to achieve such level of isolation so that my code is database independent.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Are you trying to isolate the actual database from your data access code (ie your linq to sql code from the actual queries sent to the DB)? or are you trying to test the code that uses the data access layer (ie your business rules and services)?

Comment: The letter one, now I am investigating after i have been guided by answer below, do you have any suggestion?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

> How can I test my code (TDD) for
>   standard CRUD operations without
>   having a database.

I see that the post is tagged with nunit, so I assume a .net context. Given that, I've personally utilized SQLite as an in-memory database successfully in a project for a few months time now (together with NHibernate and common DDD-patterns).

Q2:

> Is it possible to achieve such level
>   of isolation so that my code is
>   database independent.

I don't think that it's possible to write fully database independent code, but NHibernate  takes me 95% of the way there (but that number depends heavily on your specific context).

Furthermore, with good data-access patterns, e.g. «Repository» and «Unit of Work», the rest of the code base can be made 100% database agnostic. The same goes for other data sources, e.g. CSV and XML files.

Answer (score 4):

Yep.  You write an Interface with all the call to the database you would want.

Then you create two classes that implement the interface.

One has real access to your database.

The other, just pretends, it's a mock implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Use fakes, like Rhino Mocks, to mock the data access. That way when your tests run they will interact with the fake instead of going all the way down to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the business layer (and some of the presentation layer) using Mock objects.

Use Mocks/Fakes so that instead of calling the database from the DAL a fake class will be called instead and return a predefined value.

**In order to test the DAL you will need actual database**. You can use a unit testing framework to run simple CRUD on the database. Create a simple test database as well as a restore point and use the unit testing framework's setup & teardown to make sure your database is in the expected state.

Comment: seem like there is no other way around instead of loading the testing data in the state that expected.